# Global Reliance Making Unit Testing Impossible

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, logging

Background:
I am a hobbyist Python coder whose first and only project is a text-based Adventure Game **Engine** (https://github.com/zig13/scenzig).
An Adventure Game is a common first project but I realised I didn't have the creativity to write an adventure so decided instead to write a framework so someone else could do the adventure bit.
It started out as a monolithic script with no functions - at one point 712 lines long - but as I have learnt Python it has been repeatedly rewritten.

I recently learned of the concepts of unit testing and logging and I think they would be really helpful to me going forward but I have hit a snag.
The majority of my functions need access to the Adventure files and/or Character file to function.
These are accessed as a dictionary (thanks to ConfigObj) and a reference to the dictionaries is passed among the modules like this:

```
def GiveAdv(a) :
    global adv
    adv = a
    efunc.GiveAdv(a)
def GiveChar(c) :
    global char
    char = c
    argsolve.GiveChar(char)
    efunc.GiveChar(c)
```

i.e. After importing another module, a module passes on it's reference to the adventure files and character files. Later in the same module `adv.f['Actions'][str(action)]` is used to get the information on a specific action from the Actions file for example.

I've never liked this but it has been *fine* until now but is a problem now because:

1. I am trying to merge two modules rewriting much from scratch in the process and I have no way of testing as I go as everything is so inter-connected
2. Unit testing relies on a function taking arguments and producing outputs but most of mine also expect to have access to information in addition to their arguments

As I see it, Logging (using the logging module) would require somehow passing a reference to the log file around and I just can't believe that people would resort to my horrible "Give" function solution so there must be a better way.

What is the Pythonic way of giving disparate modules access to the same information, class instances and loggers?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to put the common stuff into one module and then import this module in any other module that depends on it.

Comment: Wouldn't this hypothetical module load up duplicate file references every time it was imported by another module? To be clear, nothing is hard-coded, so before this hypothetical module is useful it would need to load files/do stuff. As I understand doing it this way, the module would have to do (the same) stuff for every module that imports it. Even ignoring that inefficiency, it's not as straight-forward as loading up the same files each time. Which files are loaded depends on which Adventure is loaded and which Character from that Adventure is loaded.

Comment: The code inside the imported module will be executed only once since the module is then cached in [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) and every further import will fetch the module directly from the cache. If the data to be loaded depends on some parameters, you could put the relevant code into a function (inside that module) and have this function accept the parameters. In order to avoid reloading and duplicating in this case, you can decorate this function with [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Comment: So I kind of have a module like you are describing but it is shoe-horned into a class (https://github.com/zig13/scenzig/blob/master/classes/classAdventure.py). I just tested the concept of a single module instance being accessible from two other modules and it works as eluded to here: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules .
I'm sure I have tried this kind of strategy before but maybe where I went wrong was trying to use a Class.
I had learnt that Classes=Good and it was the only place I could see one would make sense.

Comment: I just realised I can instance the Class and refer to it from inside the module the Class is in! I create an Instance of the Adventure Class for each Adventure that is found so they can be tested but it will be trivial to create a reference inside the classAdventure module that points to the final/active Adventure. I'll write an Answer once I have got it all completely understood but I think it has clicked - thank you!